# Unable to add new line after matching a document.paragraphs - python docx library

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx, document-library

Need a help with below issue,

I have an issue adding a new line and by appending table data using python docx library by matching a string.
Document:
[Document image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/810k9.png)
Code:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Oxjj.png)

Expected result: I would like to append a table in between two paragraphs

[image: Expected result]

My result: Table added along with a string available next to matched string, means that string is also added in my table first cell along with first cell data(row 0, column 0).

[image: My result]

Please take a look at images, i would like to add new lines before and after matching a string and appending table

Comment: Please post the code as a text, not a screenshot.